# ASP.NET table strange height behavior

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app in VS2010,C#. I've created a table for my menu, it behaves strangely! I'm setting table height to X px, also row and cell heights are all set to X px. But as you can see in the following address, when mouse hovers on cells, cell height is a bit smaller than table height, in fact cell height is X px, but table height is X+4 px!!! my menu is a red bar at top of the page, what is going wrong here?

```
http://46.4.132.149/nikyar/
```

I want my hovered cells to be exactly the same height as my table height
thanks

Comment: maybe you should tag this question for `html` and `css` and skip `asp.net`

Comment: its just find, leave it that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it add to your css table `border-spacing:0`

Comment: The default for this value is 2px (2 top and 2 bottom = 4px)